# How to throw Swift exceptions when calling Foundation functions errorly?

Tags: ios, swift, exception, try-catch

I have a swift function `func hexStrToBytes(input: String) throws -> [UInt8]` to translate HEX string into Uint8 array, which may need to throw exceptions when the format of input is not correct.

But I can't verify its format by myself, instead I use `bytes.append(UInt8(str,radix: 16)!)`. If this function executes successfully, then my function can return a correct value. If something wrong with this `bytes.append(UInt8(str,radix: 16)!)`, I need to throw a exception. But how do I know it's wrong? This program may just crush and I even don't have chance to throw exceptions.

Comment: Have you read Swift 2 error handling docs? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: @Tim Thanks but I have read this before. I just feel it's not the same as what I got used to in Java. In swift, it looks I always need to throw exceptions with `guard`. But actually, there are situations that I have never imagined about, can't I just throw a exception when any error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should be close to what you're looking for. It uses optional binding to check if the string is convertible and throws an error if is not.

```
if let theByte = UInt8(str, radix: 16) {
    bytes.append(theByte) 
} else {
    throw MyError()
}
```

Note that Swift doesn't use the term "exceptions" to describe its error-handling mechanisms.  While the throw/catch control flow is similar, they are not implemented the same way as exceptions in other languages.

Comment: Thanks. So functions like `UInt8(str, radix: 16)` will always return nil if there is something wrong internal?

Comment: Yes, per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UInt8_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/UInt8/s:FVSs5UInt8cFMS_FTSS5radixSi_GSqS__), UInt8(_:radix:) returns nil if the string cannot be converted to a UInt8.